# how to debug test project and wcf service in the same ide

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, unit-testing

i have a solution with WCF service and a test project.
How can i debug the wcf calling the test method?

In the test, there is a call to local WCF in the project

Comment: You press F5 after you set a breakpoint?

Comment: the problem is that the service has a url local, like 'http:\localhost\servicename.svc' and listen to this url. if i debug the test, this project doesn't start automatically. If i press F5, i start the web project, the WCF but the debug of the test doesn't start

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to right click on solution (In solution explorer) and choose SetStartUpProjects
2. Run service in debug mode and test app via start exe file, after it another copy visual studio with this solution attach to process. (Debug -> Attach to Process)